# Write QCOW2 image to iSCSI LUN?

Tags: debian, qemu, proxmox, iscsi, qcow2

I've been trying to write a QCOW2 image to an iSCSI LUN target but have been unsuccessful. Based on [this](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/images.html#iscsi-luns) link, this should be possible (and should be possible without having to mount the iSCSI LUN as a disk) but from what error I am getting back, it's unclear to me whether what I am trying to do simply can't be done or I have a syntax error in the URL.

The OS is Debian (Proxmox).

Based on this output, the LUN should be visible:

```
root@delta-vm:~# pvesm list TrueNAS
Volid                                                Format  Type             Size VMID
TrueNAS:0.0.0.scsi-36589cfc000000f18d78a50cff1dec18b raw     images    48318386176
root@delta-vm:~# ls /dev/disk/by-path/
ip-10.0.50.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:delta-proxmox-target-lun-0  pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5.0-part1  pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5-part2
ip-10.0.60.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:delta-proxmox-target-lun-0  pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5.0-part2  pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5-part3
pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5                                                          pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5.0-part3  pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-6
pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5.0
```

But when I try this, I am confused by the error message

```
root@delta-vm:~# qemu-img convert -O raw /var/lib/vz/template/iso/Rocky-9-GenericCloud-Base.latest.x86_64.qcow2.img iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscs-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ct
l/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0
qemu-img: iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0: error while converting raw: Protocol driver 'iscsi' does not support image creation, and opening the image failed: Failed to parse URL : iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0
```

I have tried a few permutations of the URL above, but nothing seems to be working. E.g. cutting out the `iscsi-` string in URL doesn't help (the iSCSI Global Config is `iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl`):

```
root@delta-vm:~# qemu-img convert -O raw /var/lib/vz/template/iso/Rocky-9-GenericCloud-Base.latest.x86_64.qcow2.img iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/del
ta-proxmox-target-lun-0
qemu-img: iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0: error while converting raw: Protocol driver 'iscsi' does not support image creation, and opening the image failed: Failed to parse URL : iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0
```

Any clues what am I doing wrong? The iSCSI portal(s) are unauthenticated so I am providing no user/pass combination to the URL above.

For full disclosure (and I ack that this is tangential to my question), my ultimate goal with these gyrations would be to see if it's possible to re-target a disk (i.e. move storage) in qemu from local storage to iSCSI LUN but for some reason, this was never properly implemented in Proxmox so I have to take the scenic route. In other words, given this...

```
root@delta-vm:~# qm config 105
agent: 1
...
onboot: 1
scsi0: samsung:vm-105-disk-0,discard=on,iothread=1,replicate=0,size=12G,ssd=1
scsihw: virtio-scsi-single
....
```

...I'd like to substitute the `scsi0` device with the iSCSI LUN. From what I [gather](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/moving-vms-storage-to-iscsi-cant-allocate-space-in-iscsi-storage.136328/post-604552), this currently isn't possible as the code to materialise the disk image onto the LUN simply doesn't exist and an error is thrown (`storage migration failed: can't allocate space in iscsi storage`).

EDIT: Some progress - specifying the *size* argument to the directive changes the error. It looks like there is something definitely wrong with the URL

```
root@delta-vm:~# qemu-img convert -O raw /var/lib/vz/template/iso/Rocky-9-GenericCloud-Base.latest.x86_64.qcow2.img iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0 10G
qemu-img: Could not open 'iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0': Failed to parse URL : iscsi://10.0.50.1:3260/iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl/delta-proxmox-target-lun-0
```